# Mysql select uuid that contains parenthesis

Tags: mysql, select, parentheses

I'm trying to perform a simple selection

```
SELECT * FROM `table_users` WHERE uuid = '{0141fd32-599a-4af3-89fe-ecf43cdd5c22}'
```

but also if the uuid (varchar(50) fulltext) contains that value I receive 0 records. I don't want to use LIKE because I want to retreive exactly that record form the table.

Comment: I am not aware of any special meanings of curly brackets in MySQL; suspect your problem must be elsewhere. Start by inspecting the actual column content using `HEX()` to check byte values – anything unexpected there, leading/trailing whitespace, anything that doesn’t match `HEX('{0141fd32-599a-4af3-89fe-ecf43cdd5c22}')`?

Comment: The only way you get zero records for uuid = '{0141fd32-599a-4af3-89fe-ecf43cdd5c22}' is if table_users in the database your accessing doens't have a uuid of '{0141fd32-599a-4af3-89fe-ecf43cdd5c22}'  like Cbroe, I'd also compare lengths for the one you know it should match.  this will tell you if there are non-display characters in uuid causing you grief.  It may be a simple matter of using the function trim() around uuid!  but there goes the index!

Comment: this query is very basic and the data saved in your database may be different with specified.

Comment: Execute this query `SELECT * FROM table_users` and post the result here.

Comment: The issue is that It's capitalized in my db, thank you guys!